# ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.sitesallauth' in django-allauth

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

I am using Django 1.7 with python 3.4.
I am trying to use django-allauth for user authentication and I am following this link http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/
But  I am getting this problem when trying to migrate the app.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 118, in creat
e
    cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sitesallauth'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in popu
late
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in creat
e
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.sitesallauth'
```

What can be the possible reason and solution to the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the "django.contrib.sites" entry in INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you forgot to add the comma between the `django.contrib.sites` and `allauth` app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such module as `sitesallauth`, it should be `allauth`, e.g.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'django.contrib.allauth',
)
```

then install via pip:

```
pip install allauth
```

<sup>For Python 3 you may want to use `pip3`.</sup>

Simple test:

```
$ python3
>>> import django
>>> from django.contrib import auth
>>> from django.contrib import allauth
# If it fails, check if your `sys.path` is correct.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```